# Streaming audio from client to server with SignalR (dotnet 6)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr-hub

**What I want:**
I want to stream audio from the client to the server in dotnet 6. Then read and transcribe it. After that send the text back to the client in.

**What I have got so far:**

**Server code:**

```
 public class AudioRecordingHub : Hub
    {
        private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
        private MemoryStream audioStream;
        private bool isTranscribing = false;
    
   public async Task SendAudio(string base64Audio)
    {
        byte[] audioBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Audio);

        await audioStream.WriteAsync(audioBytes);

        if (!isTranscribing)
        {
            isTranscribing = true;
            await StartTranscription();
        }
    }
        
  

  public async Task StopTranscription()
        {
            if (recognizer != null)
            {
                await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
                isTranscribing = false;
            }
        }
        
        private async Task StartTranscription()
        {
            var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("<key>", "<region>");
            speechConfig.SetProperty("SpeechServiceResponse_OutputFormatOption", "Simple");
    
            var callback = new CustomPullAudioInputStreamCallback(audioStream);
            var inputStream = AudioInputStream.CreatePullStream(callback);
            var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(inputStream);
    
            recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
            recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                {
                    // Send transcribed text to the client
                    Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveText", e.Result.Text);
                }
            };
    
            await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();
        }
    }

    public class CustomPullAudioInputStreamCallback : PullAudioInputStreamCallback
    {
        private readonly MemoryStream _audioStream;
        private BinaryReader _binaryReader;
    
        public CustomPullAudioInputStreamCallback(MemoryStream audioStream)
        {
            _audioStream = audioStream;
            _binaryReader = new BinaryReader(_audioStream);
        }
    
        public override int Read(byte[] dataBuffer, uint size)
        {
            return _binaryReader.Read(dataBuffer, 0, (int)size);
        }
    
        public override void Close()
        {
            _binaryReader.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**Client code:**

```
       recordRTC = RecordRTC(stream, {
                        type: 'audio',
                        mimeType: 'audio/webm',
                        timeSlice: 1000, // Send audio chunks every 1000 ms (1 second)
                        ondataavailable: async (blob) => {
       if (connection && connection.state === signalR.HubConnectionState.Connected) {
                            const base64Audio = await blobToBase64(blob);
                            await connection.invoke('SendAudio', base64Audio);
                        }
                            }
                        

},
                });

 const blobToBase64 = (blob) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.onload = () => {
            resolve(reader.result.split(',')[1]);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
```

**My program.cs**

```
 .AddSignalR(options =>
    {
        options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // Allow messages up to 10 MB in size
    });

app
    .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapHub<AudioRecordingHub>("/audiorecordinghub");
    });
```

**Log messages from the chrome:**

- RecordRTC version:  5.6.1
- RecordRTC.min.js:15 started recording audio stream.
- RecordRTC.min.js:15 Using recorderType: MediaStreamRecorder
- RecordRTC.min.js:15 Passing following config over MediaRecorder API. {type: 'audio', - ---mimeType: 'audio/webm', timeSlice: 1000, ondataavailable: ƒ, initCallback: ƒ, …}
- RecordRTC.min.js:15 Recorder state changed: recording
- RecordRTC.min.js:15 Initialized recorderType: MediaStreamRecorder for output-type: audio
- signalr.min.js:1 [2023-04-05T15:05:25.125Z] Information: Normalizing '/audiorecordinghub' to 'https://localhost:7206/audiorecordinghub'.
- signalr.min.js:1 [2023-04-05T15:05:25.133Z] Information: WebSocket connected to - --wss://localhost:7206/audiorecordinghub?id=u1vAsklbwmPeV_MDvkp1mw.

**After this I get an error:**

- The issue now is every time SendAudio gets called all the varibles gets reset and the SpeechRecognizer Recognized event never fires.

  ```
  private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
  private MemoryStream audioStream = new();
  private bool isTranscribing = false;
  ```

**What I have tried:**

- Reading the docs
- Goggleing
- Got a bit of help from an Ai.

Is there anything else you would like to know about my issue?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Json can't send binary data. You would need to base64 encode the Uint8Array before sending it over SignalR.

Comment: Ok. I have managed to send base64 data from the client to the server and back to binary data. The issue now is that every time SendAudio gets called, all variables are reset, and the "Recognized" event on SpeechRecognizer never fires.

Comment: Please add a breakpoint to check whether you have entered the StartTranscription method?

Comment: Yes. I enter the StartTranscription method. Add all setup of the transcription code runs. But the recognized event dont fire.

Comment: I found that in your code, the asynchronous method calls the synchronous method `CustomPullAudioInputStreamCallback`, so there  `var callback` is empty or null, please delete `async` (all the async inside AudioRecordingHub  class), and use the synchronous method to test everything. If it succeeds, it can prove whether this is the reason.

Comment: I am waiting for your update, pls @me later, so that I can receive the notification in time, tks

Comment: By the way, pls check the other events in  [the official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechrecognizer?view=azure-dotnet#events), to test which event will be fired. Then we can find more details.